# How to write ITX/WTX Rule for this scenario

Tags: websphere

Input file is comma delimited and variable length file

Input:.
EmpID1,Name,DOB
EmpID1, Address, salary
EmpID2,Name,DOB,City
EmpID2, Address, Salary

Output:.
EmpID1,Name,DOB, Address, Salary
EmpID2, Name, DOB, City, address, salary

Comment: What does your input type tree look like? do you have a "employee group" that has 2 records in it (name record and address record)?

Comment: Input will be like blob since it is a variable length file